# How to test Home application?

Tags: android, android-testing, robotium, instrumentation, android-launcher

Is there any possibility to test 'Home' application?

As a test result I get:

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'. Check device logcat for details
```

When I kill it's process manually it's get restarted automatically. Maybe it's the reason why test application can't attach to `Home` application?

Comment: Just test as a regular application. Don't get what you mean if kill process.???

Comment: Any reason to do it...? You should be happy that android lets you do that at least.. getting too much inside operating system's basic applications is bad..

Comment: @xjaphx - I can't because `Instrumentation` is not getting attached to `Home` application (possibly due to it's restart)